# Test-Connection slow response

Tags: powershell

This is probably pretty simple but I ddont understand why test-connection has this behavior

If I use the command:

test-connection -computername 192.168.1.1

There is about a 3 second delay between every reply

If I use:

test-connection -computername 192.168.1.1. <-- note trailing "."

I receive replies in about 1 second intervals like a typical ping command

Any explanations?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me; they're about the same. Does the listed time actually say 3 seconds (3000 ms)? Do you get the same effect using `ping.exe` (from `cmd.exe`)? Can you try it on another computer connected to the same router? Can you try it with another destination computer/router?

Comment: Without the dot (period) test-connection to a router is very slow.  However, to another computer it's the same as with a dot.